# Alpine Linux 3.17 does not mount CephFS during boot

Tags: fstab, alpine

I have configured a CephFS fuse mount in fstab on my Alpine Linux 3.17 as follows:

`none /data fuse.ceph ceph.id=filer,ceph.client_mds_namespace=files,_netdev 0 0`

When I issue a `mount -a` the filesystem is mounted properly to `/data` as expected. However when booting the system the filesystem is not mounted but the `netmount` service seems to be active:

```
~# rc-update add netmount boot
 * rc-update: netmount already installed in runlevel `boot'; skipping
~#
```

Any ideas? I'm also wondering why I'm not able to see the netmount service on an `rc-status boot`:

```
~# rc-status boot
Runlevel: boot
 bootmisc                         [  started  ]
 networking                       [  started  ]
 syslog                           [  stopped  ]
~#
```

Comment: An "installed" service does not necessarily mean an "active" service. Have you looked into your process list by using `ps` or `top` and found a running `netmount` there? Please search for entries from `netmount` in your syslog, too.

Answer (score 0):

My Alpine Linux is running as a LXC container and `/etc/init.d/netmount` contains the following line in the `depend()` section:

```
keyword -docker -lxc -jail -prefix -systemd-nspawn -vserver
```

This makes `netmount` a no-op in my case according to https://github.com/OpenRC/openrc/blob/master/service-script-guide.md#the-depend-function

Removing the `-lxc` parameter did the trick.

However, I'm wondering why `netmount` should be a no-op in an LXC container. A properly working network setup is also needed there and this is properly in most cases the reason to defer network-dependend mounts.